# GUI to Postfix configuration

Tags: email, gui, configuration-management

#### Description

I'm looking for a front-end/GUI to Postfix's `postconf`, which makes it easier to investigate/adjust settings in `main.cf` and `master.cf`. Main goal is to get a better overview over settings already made ("active"), additional settings ("not yet active"), their relations, etc. – best with things grouped into categories (e.g. SSL/TLS settings, relaying, …).

Simple and easy-to-use solutions are preferred, focus definitely is to see connections, review settings, and have links/explanations for the used/available keywords and how to combine them best (or avoid conflicts). If your favorite goes beyond, it would at least be interesting to know about its existence – plus, if there's lack of "simple alternatives", it might turn out as the one I've got to use then. Similarly for the license part: FOSS is strongly preferred – but if not available, other solutions *might* be acceptable. But as I don't make money with the mail server (I rather have to put money to keep it running, ouch), I won't pay more than a "nominal fee" (say, USD 5) – almost nobody pays/donates me for all the services I offer (so I have to subsidize already there), which definitely lowered my willingness to do so.

#### Requirements

- must be usable on Linux (web-app is fine)
- must not apply any changes without me explicitly telling it to
- must (obviously) work with Postfix
- must show settings (active ones and unused/not-set ones) in an organized manner (categorized)

#### Nice-to-haves

- can auto-detect Postfix version and shows available/deprecated/recommended settings accordingly
- allows to make changes. If so, it should allow to "review" them first – or at least create backups of the altered files
- cares for "plugins" like Amavis (w/ SpamAssassin, ClamAV, etc)
- cares for Dovecot (which a.o. serves as auth backend via SASL here)

#### Not needed (but doesn't hurt as long as it doesn't interfere)

- user management. I already use [PostfixAdmin](http://postfixadmin.sourceforge.net/) for that – which unfortunately lacks the features to care about the other settings

---

**Update:** It shouldn't add to many other features. Certainly Webmin ([see below](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/25254/185)) has modules to deal with Postfix. But the ratio of what_I_use:what_not is rather 1:50 with that. I'd prefer a "dedicated tool" here, especially as the machine is "small sized" ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try out webmin and see if it is what you need.  **Postfix** is under the server tab.  It offers a lot more tools also.

Requirement:

Linux web app  YES  I use it that way all the time

Works with postfix   YES  see picture

Shows settings in an organized way.  YES  see picture

If you don't click **save** the settings won't be saved.

[Webmin](http://webmin.com/)
[image: actual postfix webmin screen]

It is incomplete in one area it will not show all possible settings with all not set ones.  However, it is significantly better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the update, cybernard! And yes, certainly "better than nothing" – but a bit heavy for me. Feels like buying a tank for driving to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.postfix.org/addon.html - it seems that https://www.posty-soft.org is nice.

Comment: Please (always) answer why a program meets the needs of the OP, and if you have personal experience with it

Comment: Thanks for sharing, andrej – but as none of their demos seems to be working (no server can be reached), and there are not even screenshots, it's hard to get an impression. Could you please, as Jan already suggested, take a look at our [answer guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185), [edit] your post, and add a few more details: How does it meet the requirements/nice-to-haves listed? Does it need some kind of registration (the term "api_key" seems to suggest such)? Does it run completely local (privacy is important with mail servers)?

Comment: I was looking for some postfix configuration GUI and found the list at the postfix page. As I run through commercial/half-assed/dead links haystack I found the PostY. There are some screenshots at https://www.posty-soft.org/doc_webui.html, it's for Linux, server based, seems to be doing just one thing right and free solution I am going to install and test soon so I thought that Izzy could benefit from this and maybe test it too (and score with self answer).

Comment: I finally [found it at Github](https://github.com/posty/posty_webui). Hasn't been updated since 4/2015, so it's most likely no longer maintained. Only their [Ruby API](https://github.com/posty/posty_webui) (requires Ruby) is still up-to-date (4/2018 as of this writing).